# Testing Junit no me da los resultados esperados

Tags: java, spring-boot

Tengo la siguiente base de datos:

```sql
    INSERT INTO PRICES (BRAND_ID, START_DATE, END_DATE, PRICE_LIST, PRODUCT_ID, PRIORITY, PRICE, CURR)
    VALUES (1, '2020-06-14 00:00:00', '2020-12-31 23:59:59', 1, 35455, 0, 35.50, 'EUR');
    
    INSERT INTO PRICES (BRAND_ID, START_DATE, END_DATE, PRICE_LIST, PRODUCT_ID, PRIORITY, PRICE, CURR)
    VALUES (1, '2020-06-14 15:00:00', '2020-06-14 18:30:00', 2, 35455, 1, 25.45, 'EUR');
    
    INSERT INTO PRICES (BRAND_ID, START_DATE, END_DATE, PRICE_LIST, PRODUCT_ID, PRIORITY, PRICE, CURR)
    VALUES (1, '2020-06-15 00:00:00', '2020-06-15 11:00:00', 3, 35455, 1, 30.50, 'EUR');
    
    INSERT INTO PRICES (BRAND_ID, START_DATE, END_DATE, PRICE_LIST, PRODUCT_ID, PRIORITY, PRICE, CURR)
    VALUES (1, '2020-06-15 16:00:00', '2020-12-31 23:59:59', 4, 35455, 1, 38.95, 'EUR');
```

Estoy haciendo varios test con Junit pero el resultado siempre me devuelve el primer id, sin embargo en Swagger los resultados son los correctos, es decir ingresando los parámetros startDate,brandId y productId los resultados son los que espero.

Os enseño mis clases.

```java
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "PRICES")
    @Builder
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @AllArgsConstructor
    @ToString
    @Getter
    @Setter
    public class Price {
    
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        @Column(name = "ID", nullable = false)
        private Long id;
    
        @Column(name = "START_DATE")
        private LocalDateTime startDate;
    
        @Column(name = "END_DATE")
        private LocalDateTime endDate;
    
        @Column(name = "PRICE_LIST")
        private Long priceList;
    
        @Column(name = "PRODUCT_ID")
        private Long productId;
    
        @Column(name = "PRIORITY")
        private Long priority;
    
        @Column(name = "PRICE", precision = 10, scale = 2)
        private BigDecimal price;
    
        @Column(name = "CURR")
        private String curr;
    
        @Column(name = "BRAND_ID")
        private Long brandId;
    }


    @Getter
    @Setter
    @Builder
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @AllArgsConstructor
    @ToString
    @EqualsAndHashCode
    
    @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
    public class PriceDTO {
    
        private Long id;
        private Long brandId;
    
        private LocalDateTime startDate;
    
        private LocalDateTime endDate;
        private Long priceList;
        private Long productId;
        private Long priority;
        private BigDecimal price;
        private String curr;
    
        public PriceDTO(Price price) {
    
            this.id = price.getId();
            this.brandId = price.getBrandId();
            this.startDate = price.getStartDate();
            this.endDate = price.getEndDate();
            this.priceList = price.getPriceList();
            this.productId = price.getProductId();
            this.priority = price.getPriority();
            this.price = price.getPrice();
            this.curr = price.getCurr();
    
        }
    
        public PriceDTO(PriceDTO priceDTO) {
    
    
            this.id = priceDTO.getId();
            this.brandId = priceDTO.getBrandId();
            this.startDate = priceDTO.getStartDate();
            this.endDate = priceDTO.getEndDate();
            this.priceList = priceDTO.getPriceList();
            this.productId = priceDTO.getProductId();
            this.priority = priceDTO.getPriority();
            this.price = priceDTO.getPrice();
            this.curr = priceDTO.getCurr();
        }
    }
```

```java
    @Repository
    public interface PriceRepository extends JpaRepository<Price, Long> {
    
        @Query("SELECT p FROM Price p WHERE p.brandId = :brandId AND p.productId = :productId AND :date BETWEEN " +
                "p.startDate AND p.endDate AND p.startDate <= :date ORDER BY p.priority DESC")
        Optional<List<Price>> findPricesByDateAndProductIdAndBrandIdQuery(
                @Param("date") LocalDateTime date,
                @Param("productId") Long productId,
                @Param("brandId") Long brandId);
    
    }
```

```java
    @Mapper
    public interface PriceMapper {
    
        PriceDTO priceToPriceDTO(Price price);
    
    }
```

```java
    @Service
    public interface PriceService {
    
        List<PriceDTO> getAllPrices();
    
    
        Optional<List<PriceDTO>> findPricesByDateAndProductIdAndBrandIdQuery(LocalDateTime date, Long productId, Long brandId);
    
    }

    @Service
    public class PriceServiceImpl implements PriceService {
    
        @Autowired
        private PriceRepository repository;
    
    
        private PriceMapper mapper;
    
        @Override
        public List<PriceDTO> getAllPrices() {
            List<Price> prices = repository.findAll();
            return prices.stream()
                    .map(mapper::priceToPriceDTO)
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
        }
    
        @Override
        public Optional<List<PriceDTO>> findPricesByDateAndProductIdAndBrandIdQuery(LocalDateTime date, Long productId, Long brandId) {
    
            Optional<List<Price>> optPrices = repository
                    .findPricesByDateAndProductIdAndBrandIdQuery(date, productId, brandId);
    
            return optPrices.map(prices ->
                    prices.stream()
                            .map(PriceDTO::new)
                            .collect(Collectors.toList())
    
            );
        }
    }
```

```java
    @RestController
    @RequestMapping("/api/v1/napptilus/price")
    @Slf4j
    public class PriceController {
    
        @Autowired
        private PriceService service;
    
    
        @ApiResponses(value = {
                @ApiResponse(responseCode = "200", description = "OK - Successful price found"),
                @ApiResponse(responseCode = "400", description = "Bad Request - Invalid ID supplied"),
                @ApiResponse(responseCode = "404", description = "Not Found - Price not found"),
                @ApiResponse(responseCode = "500", description = "Internal Server Error - Something went wrong on the server side")})
        @GetMapping("/query/search")
        public ResponseEntity<PriceDTO> searchPrice(@RequestParam("date") @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss") LocalDateTime date,
                                                 @RequestParam("productId") Long productId,
                                                 @RequestParam("brandId") Long brandId) {
    
            log.info("Received search request for date: {}, productId: {}, brandId: {}", date, productId, brandId);
    
            Optional<List<PriceDTO>> opt_price = service
                    .findPricesByDateAndProductIdAndBrandIdQuery
                            (date, productId, brandId);
    
            if (opt_price.isPresent() && !opt_price.get().isEmpty()) {
    
                PriceDTO priceDTO = new PriceDTO(opt_price.get().get(0));
                log.info("OK - Returning price for the request: {}", priceDTO);
                return new ResponseEntity<>(priceDTO, HttpStatus.OK);
    
            } else {
                log.warn("No price found for the request");
                return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND).build();
            }
        }

    @Nested
    @ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
    class NapptilusApplicationTests {
    
        static List<PriceDTO> listTestPrices () {
            return Arrays.asList(
                    PriceDTO.builder()
                            .id(1L)
                            .brandId(1L)
                            .startDate(LocalDateTime.parse("2020-06-14T00:00:00.00"))
                            .endDate(LocalDateTime.parse("2020-12-31T23:59:59.59"))
                            .priceList(1L)
                            .productId(35455L)
                            .priority(0L)
                            .price(new BigDecimal("35.50"))
                            .curr("EUR")
                            .build(),
    
                    PriceDTO.builder()
                            .id(2L)
                            .brandId(1L)
                            .startDate(LocalDateTime.parse("2020-06-14T15:00:00.00"))
                            .endDate(LocalDateTime.parse("2020-06-14T18:30:00.00"))
                            .priceList(2L)
                            .productId(35455L)
                            .priority(1L)
                            .price(new BigDecimal("25.45"))
                            .curr("EUR")
                            .build(),
    
                    PriceDTO.builder()
                            .id(3L)
                            .brandId(1L)
                            .startDate(LocalDateTime.parse("2020-06-15T00:00:00.00"))
                            .endDate(LocalDateTime.parse("2020-06-15T11:00:00.00"))
                            .priceList(3L)
                            .productId(35455L)
                            .priority(1L)
                            .price(new BigDecimal("30.50"))
                            .curr("EUR")
                            .build(),
    
                    PriceDTO.builder()
                            .id(4L)
                            .brandId(1L)
                            .startDate(LocalDateTime.parse("2020-06-15T16:00:00.00"))
                            .endDate(LocalDateTime.parse("2020-12-31T23:59:59.59"))
                            .priceList(4L)
                            .productId(35455L)
                            .priority(1L)
                            .price(new BigDecimal("38.95"))
                            .curr("EUR")
                            .build()
            );
        }
        @InjectMocks
        private PriceController controller;
        @Mock
        private PriceService service;
        @Autowired
        private MockMvc mockMvc;
```

```
    
        /**
         * SWAGGER TEST 4
         * {
         *   {
         *   "id": 3,
         *   "brandId": 1,
         *   "startDate": "2020-06-15T00:00:00",
         *   "endDate": "2020-06-15T11:00:00",
         *   "priceList": 3,
         *   "productId": 35455,
         *   "priority": 1,
         *   "price": 30.5,
         *   "curr": "EUR"
         * }
         */
    
        @Test
        @DisplayName("Test 4: petición a las 10:00 del día 15 del producto 35455 para la brand 1")
        void testSearchPriceTest4() {
            Long productId = 35455L;
            Long brandId = 1L;
            LocalDateTime startDate = LocalDateTime.parse("2020-06-15T10:00:00");
    
            // Lista de PriceDTOs simulada
            List<PriceDTO> listPriceDTOs = listTestPrices();
    
            // Imprimir la lista simulada para verificar su contenido
            System.out.println("List of prices in searchPrice method: " + listPriceDTOs);
    
    
            when(service.findPricesByDateAndProductIdAndBrandIdQuery(startDate, productId, brandId))
                    .thenReturn(Optional.of(listPriceDTOs));
    
            System.out.println("startDate received in service: " + startDate);
    
            // Llamar al método del servicio después de configurar el comportamiento simulado
            ResponseEntity<PriceDTO> responseDTO = controller.searchPrice(startDate, productId, brandId);
    
            // Verificar que el resultado es una respuesta exitosa (HttpStatus.OK)
            Assertions.assertThat(responseDTO.getStatusCode()).isEqualTo(HttpStatus.OK);
    
            // Verificar que el cuerpo de la respuesta no es nulo
            Assertions.assertThat(responseDTO.getBody()).isNotNull();
    
            // Verificar algunas propiedades de PriceDTO dentro del cuerpo de la respuesta
            Assertions.assertThat(responseDTO.getBody().getBrandId()).isEqualTo(brandId);
            Assertions.assertThat(responseDTO.getBody().getProductId()).isEqualTo(productId);
        }
```

Por ejemplo en este test y bueno en cualquier fecha la salida que me produce siempre es el id 1

```
2:09:26.222 [main] INFO com.napptilus.controller.PriceController -- OK - Returning price for the request: PriceDTO(id=1, brandId=1, startDate=2020-06-14T00:00, endDate=2020-12-31T23:59:59.590, priceList=1, productId=35455, priority=0, price=35.50, curr=EUR)
```

```
Cuando debería ser esto {
  "id": 3,
  "brandId": 1,
  "startDate": "2020-06-15T00:00:00",
  "endDate": "2020-06-15T11:00:00",
  "priceList": 3,
  "productId": 35455,
  "priority": 1,
  "price": 30.5,
  "curr": "EUR"
}
```

Imprimo la lista por si era nula, pero no es así

```
List of prices in searchPrice method: 
[PriceDTO(id=1, brandId=1, startDate=2020-06-14T00:00, endDate=2020-12-31T23:59:59.590, priceList=1, productId=35455, priority=0, price=35.50, curr=EUR), 
PriceDTO(id=2, brandId=1, startDate=2020-06-14T15:00, endDate=2020-06-14T18:30, priceList=2, productId=35455, priority=1, price=25.45, curr=EUR), 
PriceDTO(id=3, brandId=1, startDate=2020-06-15T00:00, endDate=2020-06-15T11:00, priceList=3, productId=35455, priority=1, price=30.50, curr=EUR), 
PriceDTO(id=4, brandId=1, startDate=2020-06-15T16:00, endDate=2020-12-31T23:59:59.590, priceList=4, productId=35455, priority=1, price=38.95, curr=EUR)]
```

Debería de buscar en esa lista la fecha startDate y devolverme un objeto PriceDTO que este en ese rango de fechas....
¿Que podría ser no serializo bien o es un problema de fechas? sigo dando un poco de vueltas.

Gracias

Comment: como mejora independiente de tu pregunta. te faltaria la repuesta 204 que es not contet que es para cuando no encuentre nada en la BD

Answer (score 0):

Como se lo que estas haciendo te doy lo que yo he hecho que se valora mucho, ademas del builder que yo no lo he implementao. Un api first hace mucho por ej. te dejo el codigo de mi proyecto que es la misma prueba que tu estas haciendo y ya miras los test
https://github.com/carlos033/PruebaInditex
Ademas te corrijo tu test.  no devuelvas en el when un optional list devuelve un objeto concreto. loq ue tu quieras que devuelva por ej

```
      @Test
  void testListarPrices() throws NotContentInditex {
    String idEmpresa = "2";
    String idtarifa = "2";
    OffsetDateTime fechaInicio = OffsetDateTime.now();

    // Crear al menos un tarifa en la lista
    Price tarifa = new Price();
    tarifa.setBrandId(idEmpresa);
    tarifa.setStartDate(fechaInicio);
    tarifa.setEndDate(fechaInicio);
    tarifa.setPriceList(2);
    tarifa.setProductID(idtarifa);
    tarifa.setPriority((short) 1);
    tarifa.setPrecio(22.0);
    tarifa.setCurr("EUR");
    Optional<Price> optTarifa = Optional.of(tarifa);


    when(repositorio.obtenerTarifaAplicar(idEmpresa, idtarifa, fechaInicio)).thenReturn(optTarifa);

    Price resultado = servicio.obtenerTarifaAplicar(idEmpresa, idtarifa, fechaInicio);

    verify(repositorio).obtenerTarifaAplicar(idEmpresa, idtarifa, fechaInicio);

    assertEquals(tarifa, resultado);
  }
```

Comment: Muchas gracias al final lo conseguí solucionar, me gusto tu proyecto lo estuve mirando jejeje